# Is there a way to draw a structure on top of another building in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, vector

Say I have a 10m-tall building that has a 2m-tall structure on top of it. How can I draw this in QGIS?

The only way I can think of is to draw a 10m tall building and then a 12m tall structure at the same location, but this doesn't seem ideal, since it makes the structure much taller than it actually is.

Comment: How do you enter the elevation of the building? Do you enter it into the attribute table?

Comment: @C.-F.Vintar Not right now (by default all buildings have elevation = 0). I imagine it is the an alternative though: add a new attribute with 0 for all buildings except this structure, which has elevation = 10. Not a pretty solution, but might still be better than the alternative.

Comment: I would have suggested the same thing you mentioned. Right now, I can not think of another solution that allows for correct data entry. You could enter this solution as an answer to your own question, than it can be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find your question a bit vague, so there are many assumptions here.
My take would be:

1. right-click your layer and click `export > Save Feature As...` and make sure to
   change the geometry to include a **z-dimension**. Now your feature has a Z-coordinate in addition to X and Y. A Z-coordinate can be seen as a foot-point of your geometry, often it is sampled from a digital elevation model (DEM), but for your purpose it can be 0 for all buildings. However, the Z-coordinate is saved in the geometry and not accessible via the attribute table.

[image]

2. Open the attribute table of your newly created and saved feature and include a new field, from where you would like to start your structure on top of another building (e.g. 10 m). In this attribute you can then enter the starting height of all structures on top of other buildings. In your example, you would put 10m in the "starting_height" and 2m in the actual height of the structure.

[image]

3. Lastly use the `Set Z value` tool and use the edit functionality to open the `Expression String Builder`

[image]

4. There you enter `0 + "height_start"`  to set the z-value (i.e. footpoint) of all buildings to 0 and add the height of all structures on top of buildings to the Z-value.

[image]

This should to the trick, however if you question was meant different make a comment below this post.